# Transposing JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5, transpose

I know there are threads on this, but I dont get it and might need help on my json file. I want to bind a json to one of my SAPUI5 controls, but I dont get it converted.

The thing is, I got my data already in the frontend, so I dont want to make a second backend call and I need to transpose my json data.

This is what I got, columns are Mon01 .. etc.

```
    Mon01   Mon02   Mon03   Mon04
0   03/2015 04/2015 05/2015 06/2015
1   1       3       5       21
2   2       4       6       22
3   10      11     12       23
```

This is what I want:

```
    Mon01   Mon02   Mon03   Mon04
0   03/2015 1       2       10
1   04/2015 3       4       11
2   05/2015 5       6       12
3   06/2015 21      22      23
```

Or in JSON what I got:

```
d : 
   [
      0: {
         Mon01: "03/2015",
         Mon02: "04/2015",
         Mon03: "05/2015",
      },
      1: {
         Mon01: "1,0",
         Mon02: "3,0",
         Mon03: "5,0",
 },
      2: {
         Mon01: "2,0",
         Mon02: "4,0",
         Mon03: "6,0",
         Mon04: "",
         Mon05: "",
         Mon06: "",
 },
      3: {
         Mon01: "10,0",
         Mon02: "11,0",
         Mon03: "12,0",
         Mon04: "",
         Mon05: "",
         Mon06: "",
 },
      length: 3
   ]
```

and in JSON what I want:

```
d : 
   [
      0: {
         Mon01: "03/2015",
         Mon02: "1,0",
         Mon03: "2,0",
         Mon04: "3,0",
         Mon05: "",
         Mon06: "",
     },
      1: {
         Mon01: "04/2015",
         Mon02: "3,0",
         Mon03: "4,0",
         Mon04: "11,0",
         Mon05: "",
         Mon06: "",
 },
      2: {
         Mon01: "05/2015",
         Mon02: "5,0",
         Mon03: "6,0",
         Mon04: "12,0",
         Mon05: "",
         Mon06: "",
 },
      length: 3
   ]
```

What I've done which is not pretty the best way (but working) a single method moving each line:

```
transpose : function(oTreeAll) {

    var oTreeNew = new Array();
    var oTreeSingle = {};

oTreeSingle.Mon01 = oTreeAll[0].Mon01.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle.Mon02 = oTreeAll[1].Mon01.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle.Mon03 = oTreeAll[2].Mon01.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle.Mon04 = oTreeAll[3].Mon01.replace(',', '.');
oTreeNew.push(oTreeSingle);

var oTreeSingle1 = {};
oTreeSingle1.Mon01 = oTreeAll[0].Mon02.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle1.Mon02 = oTreeAll[1].Mon02.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle1.Mon03 = oTreeAll[2].Mon02.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle1.Mon04 = oTreeAll[3].Mon02.replace(',', '.');
oTreeNew.push(oTreeSingle1);

var oTreeSingle2 = {};
oTreeSingle2.Mon01 = oTreeAll[0].Mon03.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle2.Mon02 = oTreeAll[1].Mon03.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle2.Mon03 = oTreeAll[2].Mon03.replace(',', '.');
oTreeSingle2.Mon04 = oTreeAll[3].Mon03.replace(',', '.');
oTreeNew.push(oTreeSingle2);

var data = {
    "d" : {
        "results" : oTreeNew,
    }
};

    return data;
},
```

**How would you do it? I've read a lot about map functions, but I dont understand the way the work or how to adapt it to my json, can anyone help me with it? THANKS ALOT!**

---

### Thanks to Shibaji Chakraborty, I got the solution for my json:

```
transpose : function(oTreeAll) {

    var keys = [];
    var i = 0;
    for ( var key in oTreeAll[i]) {
        keys.push(key);
    }

    console.log(keys);

    var newObj = {
        d : []
    };

    newObj['length'] = oTreeAll.length;
    for (var k = 0; k < oTreeAll.length; k++) {
        var obj = {};
        for ( var cnt in keys) {
            obj[keys[cnt]] = "";
        }
        newObj.d.push(obj);
    }

    for (var k = 0; k < oTreeAll.length; k++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < oTreeAll.length; j++) {
            newObj.d[k][keys[j]] = oTreeAll[j][keys[k]];
        }
    }

    console.log(newObj);
            return newObj;

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the code below:

```
var data = {d : 
[
  {
     Mon01: "03/2015",
     Mon02: "04/2015",
     Mon03: "05/2015",
  },
  {
     Mon01: "1,0",
     Mon02: "3,0",
     Mon03: "5,0",
  },
  {
     Mon01: "2,0",
     Mon02: "4,0",
     Mon03: "6,0",
     Mon04: "",
     Mon05: "",
     Mon06: "",
  },
  {
     Mon01: "10,0",
     Mon02: "11,0",
     Mon03: "12,0",
     Mon04: "",
     Mon05: "",
     Mon06: "",
}
],
        length: 3};

//console.log(data.d[0]);
var keys = [];
for(var key in data.d[data.length]){
   //console.log(key);
  keys.push(key);
}

var newObj = {d:[]};
newObj['length'] = data.length;
for(var k =0;k<data.length;k++){
  var obj = {};
  for(var cnt in keys){
    obj[keys[cnt]] = "";
  }
  newObj.d.push(obj);
 }
for(var k =0;k<data.length;k++){
   //var obj = {};
  //console.log(k);
  for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
    newObj.d[k][keys[j]] = data.d[j][keys[k]];
  }
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: hey Shibaji, ist pretty Close, currently in keys there is "0", "1" because in my json there is another Level than in yours --> d :  [  0: { Mon01: "03/2015", .... could you help me?