# Not able to print data from tables using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

This the the element that I am trying to find:

```
tbody class="searchable ng-scope" ng-repeat="ut in vm.unitList | filter: (leaseLength: (vm.weekOption.value I l
"')}">…</tbody>

**Xpath - //*[@id="no-more-tables"]/tbody**
```

And this is my code:

```
driver.get(url)
[enter image description here][1]
property_name = driver.title
print('Property =====',property_name)

rooms = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="no-more-tables"]/tbody')
print (len(rooms))
```

The length of rooms are coming 0 even though I gave the correct xpath.
Ideally it should come 5

Comment: what is the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire https://www.hellostudent.co.uk/student-accommodation/stoke/caledonia-mills/

Comment: @platipus_on_fire i want to get the data of class - searchable ng-scope

so for that I am looping on searchable ng-scop.. as there are total 5 such tbody class.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire can you please post it by using selenium?

this is not the only URL I'm trying to scrape.

There are more 29 other URLS with the same structure but different property names.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire When I convert the table to json. The json file is made like this -

{
    "ROOM TYPE": {
        "0": "Bronze Studio",
        "1": "Silver Studio",
        "2": "Silver Studio",
        "3": "Gold Studio"
    },

And so onn..

How should I convert like this - 

{
    "0": {
        "ROOM TYPE": "Bronze Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": null,
        "WEEKS": null,
        "START DATE": null,
        "AVAILABILITY": "Sold Out"
    },

Comment: You need to transpose that json. See this question it will help you do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081454/transposing-json-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in that page is being loaded dynamically by Javascript, after loading the html. The following code will (remove the complexities of selenium and) get you the data you're after:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

s = requests.Session()

data = {"route":"unitlist","command":"","data":"{\"list\":{\"filter\":{\"propertyNoFilter\":\"PR0170000\",\"dateFilter\":\"03/09/2022\"}}}"}
r = s.get('https://www.hellostudent.co.uk/student-accommodation/stoke/caledonia-mills/')
r = s.post('https://rooms.hellostudent.co.uk/DynamicsNav/Call', data=data)
# print(r.json()['list']['property'])
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['list']['property'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
unitType    unitSubType unitDescription noOfUnits   mainPropertyNo  startDate   endDate leaseLength pricePerWeek    biannualAvailable   termPaymentAvailable    features
0   SHAPT   SHAPT-Q4-B4-ES  Silver 4-Bed Apartment Ensuite  0   PR0170000   03/09/22    25/08/23    51  89.00   false   true    None
1   SHAPT   SHAPT-Q4-B3-ES  Silver 3-Bed Apartment Ensuite  12  PR0170000   03/09/22    25/08/23    51  93.00   false   true    None
2   SHAPT   SHAPT-Q4-B2-ES  Silver 2-Bed Apartment Ensuite  7   PR0170000   03/09/22    25/08/23    51  115.00  false   true    None
3   STUDIO  STUDIO-Q4   Silver Studio   1   PR0170000   03/09/22    25/08/23    51  153.00  false   true    None
4   STUDIO  STUDIO-Q3   Gold Studio 0   PR0170000   03/09/22    25/08/23    51  169.00  false   true    None
```

If you want to do it with selenium, bear in mind data is in an iframe:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.hellostudent.co.uk/student-accommodation/stoke/caledonia-mills/'
browser.get(url)

iframe = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='panel__frame']")))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
t.sleep(5)
rooms_table = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[id='no-more-tables']")))
df = pd.read_html(str(rooms_table.get_attribute('outerHTML')))
print(df[0])
browser.quit()
```

Which would display the dataframe:

```
ROOM TYPE   PRICE PER WEEK/PER PERSON   WEEKS   START DATE  AVAILABILITY
0   Silver 4-Bed Apartment Ensuite  NaN NaN NaN Sold Out
1   Silver 3-Bed Apartment Ensuite  £93 51.0    03/09/22    Available - Book Now
2   Silver 2-Bed Apartment Ensuite  £115    51.0    03/09/22    Available - Book Now
3   Silver Studio   £153    51.0    03/09/22    Last few remaining - book now
4   Gold Studio NaN NaN NaN Sold Out
```

It would make more sense to actually scrape the url that iframe is loading from: https://rooms.hellostudent.co.uk/#/RoomAvailability/caledonia-mills